# Manage Jenkins page is not showing proper options i.e Configure System, Global Tool Configuration, Manage Plugin

Tags: jenkins

Manage Jenkins page is not showing proper options i.e Configure System, Global Tool Configuration, Manage Plugin. Its showing only System, Tool, Plugins

[image]

Proper option should be shown i.e- Configure System, Global Tool Configuration, Manage Plugin.

Comment: Are you logged in as the admin?

Comment: Yes, i have logged in as admin.